# Oracle APEX:4.2 - creating Expand and Collapse option in Oracle Apex Classic report

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I am using **Oracle APEX 4.2** version.

I have created the `Classic report` on Page 3 and added the extra column 'Details' which holds the link `Show Details` (used `<div>` in SQL query).

`'<div onclick="showdetail(this,'|| "ITEM" ||')" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;">show_detail</div>' Detail`.

`OnClick` event on show details, it should generate an `Iframe` to display the report available on Page 4 by setting the Item value in Page 4 hidden item as `ITEM` value of row in Page 3 classic report.

Demo :
Workspace: **DC8909**

UserName: **TEST**

Password: **test**

Application: **47049**

Link: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/

Comment: You need to write your own Javascript function called `showDetail` that does whatever you want, e.g. shows and updates the `src` of an iframe defined in an HTML region.

Comment: Note that your function calls currently look like `showdetail(this,MOUSE)` which isn't right, it should be e.g. `showdetail(this,'MOUSE')`